# iOS: Why custom view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

So far I came across many developers are using Custom view controllers instead of .xib file often. Can anyone tell me that which one is the best way? using custom or static?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain?

Comment: there no difference between view controller create using  .xib or create programatically

Comment: many developers are using few xib files only for entire app even if they need many to do the app easier. but many other developers are using many xib files instead of creating it dynamically by code So my question is which one is best for standard developer?

Comment: Either you can develop UI using xib file or directly from code. Or it can also be hybrid like in a single view you do partial UI development from xib and code. It purely depends up on the need of the application. Generally staic views are developed from xib and dynamic views are from code.

Answer (score 0):

It's your wish, use what ever you feel is easy for you. I prefer custom , because it gives me much more freedom to play with my custom views. Yes it is much more laborious , but you have more control over it(what i personally feel).
It would be great if you elaborate your question...

here is a small example where i used custom. The data to create views (like textfields , buttons etc) was being provided to me in form of XML (from server). So this XML can be changed any time at server end. which means  if my view is rendering 3 textfields today, on changing xml it shows 10 textfields. So if your view is not static or fixed, you should use custom method.

In IN SHORT - fixed or static view -use xib (you can use custom also). in case of dynamic,you can (should) do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you are designing UI with code (not using Xib/Stotyboard) this will be good when you create UI dynamically so then you need not to spend more time on changes. what ever we use for development (Code/Xib/Storyboard) nothing will be changed in performance. As per user/developer comfort we will go for it. Suppose there are lot of UI need to be displayed few at the time viewdidload and rest after some button action then usually at the initially stage itself Xib and Story board will load all of them and hides un wanted and as per actions it will show the hidden UI. i feel coding is better for me.